# Area51 report says Workplace is on pace for 3 users with 3,000+ rep instead of 4

Tags: support, beta, statistics

Area51 report says Workplace is on pace for 3 users with 3,000+ rep. <sup>if memory serves, yesterday it said "4 users"</sup>

How are report statistics calculated?

"On pace for 3 users" looks quite confusing because "Top Users" list right below shows 3 users with reputation over 3500 - and I checked that these guys have it **over 3K for about a week at least**.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, the metric's pretty annoying because it almost always shows the current count unless you're getting 3k rep users left and right early on (due to the formula in NickC's answer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I looked at this a while back and I think the formula is:

**3000 rep users per day** = (rep users now) / (days in beta)

**projected 3000 rep users at 90 days** = FLOOR((3000 rep users per day) × 90)

For us that means...

We have 3 users / 75 days in beta = 0.04 3000users/day

FLOOR(0.04 × 90) = FLOOR(3.6) = **3**.

Comment: I would upvote twice if I could. Somehow, this meaning of _pace_ completely escaped my mind

Comment: @gnat IMO the more logical way to interpret it is "how many users are on pace" not "the site is on pace to have X users", meaning the pace would be the relative rep gain of the users, not the 3k rep users per day. But that would be a lot more expensive to calculate.

Comment: I would think it would be number of users with rep > 3000*(# of days in beta/90).  But that number would be 2500 at 75 days so would be the same.